# Cannot install google play store on xiaomi Redmi2

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Google play store stopped working so i tried to uninstall/reinstall it

The problem is that when i try to install it by the Google Installer app (i downloaded the apk of the google installer and transferred it by usb) the download automatically pauses as soon as it starts and remains paused forever... In the notifications, google installers says that its "waiting for network"

Im using a functional wi-fi connection (can use the internet in other apps without any issue).

I already tried to:
Unistall updates/force stop/clean data of Google Play Services (wich is already installed);
Removed my google account;
Added a fresh google account;
Restarted the device several times;
Try to install using other internet conections;

but i just cant make it work...

Does anybody have a clue on how to solve this issue?

The device is a xiaomi HM 2LTE-BR, Android version 4.4.4 KTU84P

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Gapps, download and flash it through recovery mode